# delete content of a file except specific patterns

Tags: regex, bash, awk, sed, grep

I have a file that contains multiples informations, i'm trying to delete all the content of the file except a specific pattern that i want as a list.

The pattern is like this:

```
/[csc]-[ALPHANUM of 4]-[ALPHANUM]-[ALPHANUM of 3]-[NUM of 8]/
```

The pattern always have `csc` at the start but can be in the middle of the lines.
It has `/` athe the start of the pattern and at the end sometimes (if this could help) but i just need what's between.

Example :

```
/csc-dbc1-repo01x-x11-20210101/
```

i tried to do something like this :

```
grep 'csc-[a-z0-9]{4}-[a-z0-9]-[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{8}' file1
```

But it returns nothing. Is there anyway i can have these patterns listed in the file.

Expected result :

```
csc-dbc1-repo01x-x11-20210301
csc-dvc1-rmco01x-x12-20220104
csc-cbc1-revehq1-A11-20210101
```

Extract of lines from the file containing a pattern :

```
"assets" : [ {
  "downloadUrl" : "https://URL/repository/doc/v&/PROJECT/SUBP/csc-dbc1-repo01x-x11-20210301/DIR/DIR2",
  "path" : "v&/PROJECT/SUBP/csc-dbc1-repo01x-x11-20210301/DIR/DIR2",
```

Comment: In your specification of the "pattern" you include `-[ALPHANUM]-` in the middle but ITYM `-[ALPHANUM of 7]-` or similar given your sample input. That specification mistake is carried into your code.

Comment: Your "Extract of lines" looks like your real input might be JSON or YAML or some other structured text. If so, parse it using a tool that understands that language, not a mix of sed, awk, grep, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `sed`

```
$ sed -En 's/.*(csc-[[:alnum:]-]+).*/\1/p' input_file
csc-dbc1-repo01x-x11-20210301
csc-dbc1-repo01x-x11-20210301
```

Answer (score 2):

```
csc-[a-zA-Z0-9]{4}-[a-zA-Z0-9]+-[a-zA-Z0-9]{3}-[0-9]{8}
```

This one matches the examples you gave.
Or you could search for case insensitive as Wiktor Stribiżew did so you can avoid adding more patterns to the regexp

```
csc-[a-z0-9]{4}-[a-z0-9]+-[a-z0-9]{3}-[0-9]{8}
```

Answer (score 1):

With GNU `awk` you could try following code, written and tested with shown samples only. Simple explanation would be, using regex `(\\/|\n|[[:space:]])csc(-[[:alnum:]]+)+` to get expected output as per OP's requirement and setting it into `RS` variable of `awk`. In main program substituting extra part and printing only required part out of it.

```bash
awk -v RS='(\\/|\n|[[:space:]])csc(-[[:alnum:]]+)+' '
RT{
  sub(/^\/|[[:space:]]|\n/,"",RT)
  print RT
}
'  Input_file
```